# Can this statement be regarded as a class invariant?

Tags: computer-science, semantics, design-by-contract, invariants

This is a highly general thought, but let's use C# in this example.

Given that

- I have a disposable class `Foo`, *i.e.*, it implements `IDisposable`.
- `Foo` has a boolean flag `disposed` that is **false** until `Dispose` is called, after which it's **true**.
- All public methods of `Foo` throws `ObjectDisposedException` if `disposed` is **true** when they are called.

Does this statement

> Any method of `Foo`, except `Dispose`, will throw an `ObjectDisposedException` when called on an instance of `Foo` that has been disposed.

describe an invariant of `Foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

This is a set of rules common to all the methods of the class. Invariants are not rules for methods.

Design by Contract comprises defining the following parts of a contract:

- Method preconditions
- Method postconditions
- Class invariant

What you are describing are method postconditions. They belong to the contract of each function (which is of course part of the contract of the class), but not to the class invariant.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an invariant. It's a statement about the state of object. IMO, what you described is a dispose method's postcondition and postcondition of all methods.